# Continuous crashes of WebKitWebProcess

Tags: 16.04, webkit

My `kern.log` file has large number of log entries as below. I could not figure out who is embedding webkit. Only WebkitWebProcesses I could find were started by upstart, but I am not sure if it's the same upstart process firing all these WebkitWebProcesses.

I normally have Chrome, Thunderbird and Eclipse running. Suspecting eclispe because of first two don't use WebkitWebProcess, but no way to prove it to log the bug.

How do I find who embedded Webkit that is causing all these crashes?

```
Apr 13 10:55:23 nrao-XPS-8700 kernel: [1124110.246447] WebKitWebProces[19627]: segfault at bbadbeef ip 00007fd77d15b48c sp 00007ffeaad04bb0 error 6 in libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18.5.8[7fd77c3f2000+f57000]
Apr 13 10:55:26 nrao-XPS-8700 kernel: [1124112.500453] WebKitWebProces[19641]: segfault at bbadbeef ip 00007f9d3059148c sp 00007ffcf5dba520 error 6 in libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18.5.8[7f9d2f828000+f57000]
Apr 13 11:00:13 nrao-XPS-8700 kernel: [1124400.426251] WebKitWebProces[20247]: segfault at bbadbeef ip 00007f941c22548c sp 00007ffcb2e2def0 error 6 in libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18.5.8[7f941b4bc000+f57000]
```